# drops a column if it exceeds a specific number of NA values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

i want to write a program that drops a column if it exceeds a specific number of NA values .This is what i did.

```
def check(x):
for column in df:
    if df.column.isnull().sum() > 2:
        df.drop(column,axis=1)
```

there is no error in executing the above code , but while doing  `df.apply(check)`, there are a ton of errors.

P.S:I know about the thresh arguement in `df.dropna(thresh,axis)`

Any tips?Why isnt my code working?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, create a mask and apply. The key to efficient pandas is to avoid loops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think best here is use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with parameter `thresh`:

> thresh : int, optional
>
> Require that many non-NA values.

So for vectorize solution subtract it from length of `DataFrame`:

```
N = 2
df = df.dropna(thresh=len(df)-N, axis=1)
print (df)
   A  D    E  F
0  a  1  5.0  a
1  b  3  3.0  a
2  c  5  6.0  a
3  d  7  9.0  b
4  e  1  2.0  b
5  f  0  NaN  b
```

---

I suggest use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) for apply function for input `DataFrame` with change `df.column` to `df[column]`, because dot notation with dynamic column names from variable failed (it try select column name `column`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,5,np.nan],
                   'C':[np.nan,8,np.nan,np.nan,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,np.nan],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A    B    C  D    E  F
0  a  NaN  NaN  1  5.0  a
1  b  NaN  8.0  3  3.0  a
2  c  NaN  NaN  5  6.0  a
3  d  5.0  NaN  7  9.0  b
4  e  5.0  2.0  1  2.0  b
5  f  NaN  3.0  0  NaN  b

def check(df):
    for column in df:
        if df[column].isnull().sum() > 2:
            df.drop(column,axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df
            
print (df.pipe(check))
   A  D    E  F
0  a  1  5.0  a
1  b  3  3.0  a
2  c  5  6.0  a
3  d  7  9.0  b
4  e  1  2.0  b
5  f  0  NaN  b
```

Comment: worked, btw why is  ` apply ` method not applicable here?

Comment: Because `.apply` loop with each column or row separately, here need input all `DataFrame`

Answer (score 4):

Although jezrael's answer works that is not the approach you should do. Instead, create a mask: `~df.isnull().sum().gt(2)` and apply it with `.loc[:,m]` to access columns.

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':list('abcdef'),
    'B':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,5,np.nan],
    'C':[np.nan,8,np.nan,np.nan,2,3],
    'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
    'E':[5,3,6,9,2,np.nan],
    'F':list('aaabbb')
})

m = ~df.isnull().sum().gt(2)
df = df.loc[:,m]

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   A  D    E  F
0  a  1  5.0  a
1  b  3  3.0  a
2  c  5  6.0  a
3  d  7  9.0  b
4  e  1  2.0  b
5  f  0  NaN  b
```

**Explanation**

Assume we print the columns and the mask before applying it.

```
print(df.columns.tolist())
print(m.tolist())
```

It would return this:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
[True, False, False, True, True, True]
```

Columns B and C are unwanted (False). They are removed when the mask is applied.

Comment: Thank,. As a beginner in pandas programming, could you explain the use  "~df" in your code?Also I tried to read the official pandas.df.mask page , but couldnot understand anything .Are you aware of some simpler examples of mask functionality?

Comment: @DRPR Ok the thing is... with mask all I mean is an array with True and False. The `~` sign does one thing. It makes True->False and False->True. In your case you want to remove the columns with > 2 but actually if you turn it around, you want to keep the columns which **NOT** meet this criteria.

Comment: @jpp - I agree, better is use vectorized solutions, so answer was edited with `dropna`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `count` which counts non-null values

```
In [23]: df.loc[:, df.count().gt(len(df.index) - 2)]
Out[23]:
   A  D    E  F
0  a  1  5.0  a
1  b  3  3.0  a
2  c  5  6.0  a
3  d  7  9.0  b
4  e  1  2.0  b
5  f  0  NaN  b
```

Comment: most understandable answer for me.Thanks